# WooCommerce Checkout for prepayment doesn't work on Safari

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having the problem that the checkout while using prepayment doesn't work on my WooCommerce website on Safari. When I want to checkout it says "We were unable to process your order, please try again". On Firefox and Chrome everything works fine.

My website:
[www.hejbarn.de](https://hejbarn.de)

Thank you and best regards
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was caused by a plugin called "German Market". There I had to turn off everything under the category: Allgemein/Bestellvorgang/Checkout Template